# C# Не могу подключить System.Web

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Бесконечно загружается следующая вещь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, кто сталкивался с этим

Comment: уберите текст "(из System.Web)"

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это студия его написала

Comment: У меня тоже такое часто бывает, когда анализатор предлагает добавить библиотеку. Зависает надолго. Тоже решаю проблему добавлением вручную.

Comment: У меня тоже такое бывает, и тоже добавляю вручную. Видимо какой-то баг в студии при попытке автоматом подцепить референс. Ставлю плюс, вопрос по факту актуальный и решение ниже верное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил ссылку вручную через окно просмотра решения и всё заработало